# Wrong Date displayed

Tags: javascript

I have the following in an html file to display today's Date.

```html
<p id="todays-date">
   <script>
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var day = currentDate.getDay();
      var month = currentDate.getMonth();
      var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
      var fullDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
      document.write(fullDate);
   </script>
</p>
```

As for today being the 23rd of September 2021 23/9/2021 in Australia
the result I am getting is 4/8/2021.

Any help would be appreciated.

MiltonT.

Comment: @PietroNadalini Nope. The `4` is caused by `getDay()`.

Answer (score 2):

`getDay` returns the current weekday and `getMonth` returns the current month, starting from 0

I would recommend you to take a look at the [Date API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```js
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var day = currentDate.getDate(); // Returns the day of the month (1–31) for the specified date according to local time.
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1; // Returns the month (0–11) in the specified date according to local time.
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var fullDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    
    document.write(fullDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

- `getDay` gives you the day of the week, not the date. use `getDate` instead.
- `getMonth` is zero-based. (january is 0, not 1). Add 1 to get the conventional one-based month.

Answer (score 0):

Replace getDay with getDate, [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns the day of the week
0 represent Sunday and 6 represent Saturday. So 4 here in your question represent thursday

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var day = currentDate.getDate();
var month = currentDate.getMonth();
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
var fullDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
document.write(fullDate);
```

Comment: I would also add 1 to the month, so the output looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var currentDate = new Date();
console.log(currentDate.toLocaleString('en-US'));


// 9/23/2021, 10:28:46 AM
```

YOu will get output in above format

Answer (score 0):

Hello the mistake you did here is you fetched day instead of date.

The second mistake is months count from 0 to 11 instead of 1-12 increment by 1 will solve your problem

here is modified version of your code

```js
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var day = currentDate.getDate();
      var month = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
      var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
      var fullDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
      window.alert(fullDate);
```

js months calculate from 0-11 instead of 1-12

Comment: I also have images that have an id of the date in the format 23/9/2021 etc and I would like to be able to make a calculation to exclude any images that are less than todays date. Is this possible?